# Ajax form not submitting - Rails 5

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to submit the following form using ajax

```
      <%= form_tag contact_form_submission_path, remote: true do %>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, required: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Name" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= email_field :email, nil, required: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Email" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= text_area_tag :message, nil, required: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "message", rows: '12' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-brand btn-round pull-right btn-sm'%>

      <% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
post "/contact_form_submission", to: "pages#contact_form_submission"
```

**Controller**

```
  def contact_form_submission
   puts 'Form submit action triggered'
  end
```

**contact_form_submission.js.erb**

```
$("form")[0].reset();
```

I've used this exact setup on countless occasions, and it usually works fine. However this form will not submit. I'm not getting any terminal output at all when hitting submit, and there are no console errors.

Is there something elsewhere that is required for Ajax to work that I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<%= form_tag contact_form_submission_path, remote: true do %>
```

with

```
<%= form_tag "/contact_form_submission", remote: true do %>
```

also check is there any filter before action `contact_form_submission`